# Existe variável de sessão no Json [web service]?

Tags: android, json, web-service, sharedpreferences

Bom, o mini mundo de meu projeto é o seguinte:

> Estou criando um aplicativo, onde irei consumir um banco de dados pelo método json, onde eu valido o usuário logado, porem quando for requisitado para adicionar alguma outra informação no próprio banco, como irei identificar que o usuário X está adicionando e não usuário Y ? O método que pensei é gravar uma variável de sessão, assim, sempre saberei que o usuário X do celular x, está adicionando um conteúdo.

Existe alguma solução para esta duvida ?
Preciso de um norte para estudar mais sobre isto. Agradeço aquele que colaborar com algo.

Visão do usuário:

> Suponhamos que sou o usuário do aplicativo: Preciso fazer login para acessar as minhas informações, apos isto tenho a possibilidade de cadastrar novo aluno, fazer chamada para este aluno, além de poder fazer um relatório para como foi a aula.

Visão do programador:

> Preciso gravar os dados do login efetuado pelo usuário onde eu possa identificar de que informações eu precise alterar, pois podem existir vários usuário logados e cada usuário fazer parte de uma escola por exemplo. Ao usuário efetuar o cadastro do aluno, é necessário identificar qual usuário está fazendo isto, poderia utilizar por meio do sharedPreferences porem meu programa ficaria veraneável para qualquer tipo de hacker.

Não seria necessário para mim, utilizar login por meio do facebook, outlook, gmail entre outros, pois não são todas as pessoas que tem estes logins, alem do que, preciso cadastrar previamente o "professor" pois apenas liberarei acesso as pessoas cadastradas em meu sistemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só para esclarecer a nomenclatura: JSON não é um método, é simplesmente um forma de representar objetos como uma cadeia de caracteres. Essa forma é usada para transmitir os dados enviados e recebidos pelos web services que você escreve para interagir com o banco.

Quando você validar o usuário, poderá mandar junto com o JSON de resposta o id do usuário no banco. Guarde esse id no seu aplicativo Android, por exemplo em Shared Preferences.

Quando seu aplicativo for fazer uma operação no banco (através de uma chamada a web service, nunca diretamente no banco), deverá passar o id do usuário como parâmetro para o web service, assim ele saberá que a operação está sendo feita pelo usuário com esse id.

Chamadas a Web Services são simples requisições HTTP. Uma requisição HTTP (e sua respectiva resposta) tem corpo e cabeçalho. As formas mais comuns de requisitar (essas sim chamadas de "métodos") são HTTP GET e HTTP POST. No caso do HTTP GET os parâmetros vão junto com a URL da requisição. No caso do HTTP POST vão no corpo da requisição, separados da URL.

Dependendo da biblioteca que você estiver usando para chamar web services essa coisa de corpo e cabeçalho pode ser abstraída para o desenvolvedor, mas de qualquer forma é bom entender essas coisas.

Essa é uma forma de fazer. Não requer nenhuma variável de sessão; quando muito, você guarda um token de autenticação que é retornado pelo web service de validação do usuário e pode ser incluído nas chamadas subsequentes, assim você não precisa ficar validando o usuário de novo a cada requisição.

Há outras formas, inclusive gerando o token de autenticação de forma que nele esteja encriptado o id do usuário, e decriptando do lado do servidor para reaver esse id. Nesse caso não é necessário enviar o id a cada requisição, pois ele já está incluído no token. Vai depender de como você está implementando a autenticação de usuário.

---

**EDIT:** A sua preocupação com algum *hacker* acessar suas Shared Preferences é o que deveria fazer você não reinventar a roda e usar uma solução como OAuth2. Tenha em mente que para alguém que não seja o próprio aplicativo acessar esse dado o aparelho precisa ser *rootado*, ou seja, estar na posse do hacker e ter o acesso *root* desbloqueado. Não é uma situação corriqueira. Há outros cenários com que se preocupar e uma solução como OAuth2 se propõe a evitá-los sem que o desenvolvedor precise dominar essa área, que é complexa, e escrever código do zero.

Comment: Tem algum site para que possa me indicar sobre este token ? Preciso ler mais sobre isto, e aprender como implementar ? Se souber de alguma vídeo aula em produção, seria grato.

Comment: Esse assunto de autenticação é cabeludo, eu mesmo não entendo muito. O pessoal costuma recomendar que não se reinvente a roda nesse caso, em vez disso dê preferência a algo pronto como OAuth2. Se você detalhar melhor o seu cenário (quais são as credenciais usadas, se de Facebook, Google, ou outro caso), preferencialmente em uma outra pergunta aqui no SOPT, o pessoal pode ajudar mais.

Comment: Dei mais uma incrementada na minha pergunta, vê se consegue entender, e se ha algo para me auxiliar.

Comment: Complementei a resposta.

Comment: não achei nada que refere ao OAuth2 para o uso que preciso, não interesso em utilizar o facebook ou algo do tipo para autenticar, preciso que seja autenticado com o meu servidor. Teria como me auxiliar para encontrar algo que utilize isto especifico ? Ou teria outra solução (em português) para me apresentar ?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 é genérico, não tem relação com Facebook ou Google (citei esses serviços porque oferecem APIs próprias para a autenticação). E tem um problema: não consegui encontrar tutoriais em português para o Android, somente em inglês.